# How to write a multiple criteria index-match that averages all occurrences of results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the average of all occurrences in column C based on an index-match search of column A and B.

Here is the example data:

**A** **B** **C**

1 10 85

1 10 80

2 20 83

2 20 75

Currently, my function is this

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(C2:C5,MATCH(1&10,A2:A5&B2:B5,0)))
```

This produces the value 85. I would like to take the average of both 85 and 80.

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this typical `AVERAGEIFS()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like typically a case for `AVERAGEIFS()`, average a specific column with certain criteria in other columns e.g. your 1 in column A and 10 in column B.

So try:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C1:C5,A1:A5,1,B1:B5,10)
```